# Media player that plays .m4v files?

Tags: video, mediaplayer

If I wanted to play some .m4v files (non-DRM Apple TV as they're produced through Handbrake), what would be the best HD Media Player to play back the files?

Would this one work?

http://www.ebuyer.com/product/249286

I've heard bad things about this player though, so wondering if there's one that would play .m4v as well as the usual .avi, .mpg etc. and codecs as shown in that link?

Just looking for something reliable that will play those sorts of files.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PS3 will do a great job of it. That's what I use. The only downside is that a PS3 won't natively play mkv files, but you can use [PS3 Media Server](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/) to live-transcode and stream from your computer to the PS3.

Comment: A PS3 is a heckuva media player.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments - I think a PS3 would be great, just weighing up costs, but I like the way you can keep media on a Hard Drive and then plug it in to the PS3 as well as using it as a games console.

Answer (score 1):

i have a roku xd|s and it plays mp4, mkv, m4v and wmv very well!

i should follow up -- i my roku with roksbox to stream media off my laptop to my television.  handbrake will also convert all those pesky formats it doesn't support to the correct versions.

i've got a decent encoding profile set up in handbrake if you're interested.

the xd|s also allows a usb drive attached which will allow local playback of mkv/h264 files.

we are so happy with ours we actually got rid of cable (hulu plus and netflix and amazon vod)

Answer (score 0):

iTunes will play them. According to this [iTunes: Frequently asked questions about viewing and syncing videos](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2729):

- Video content purchased from the iTunes Store.
- QuickTime and MPEG-4 movie files that end in ".mov", ".m4v", or ".mp4" and are playable in QuickTime Player.
- Video podcasts.
- iTunes Digital Copies.
- iTunes Store Movie Rentals (Requires iTunes 9 or later).

Comment: Why the down vote, this answer is perfectly correct

Comment: He's looking for a hardware player. He knows iTunes plays the file already.

Comment: yeah, I was being stupid. This answer doesn't answer his question.